# passing arguments to a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, argument-passing

I have a thread to which i wish to pass 3 arguments. So, i put them in a struct as follows:

```
struct arg
{
time_t  time1;
float name1;
time_t quantum1;
};
```

I passed the arguments the following way:

```
 arg arg1;
 arg1.time1=(time_t)(int)job.peek(); //job.peek() was 3
 cout<<"job time is "<<arg1.time1<<endl; //this output 3

 arg1.name1=(float)(int)job.returnname(NULL); //job.returnname() was 1
 cout<<"job name is "<<arg1.name1<<endl;// this output 1

 arg1.quantum1=quantum; //quantum was 7
 cout<<"quantum is "<<arg1.quantum1<<endl;//this output 7

 pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, func3, (void*)(&arg1));
```

But when i checked these values at the beginning of the thread itself, they were changed.

```
 void* timer(void *argum)
 {
 arg *arg1= (arg*)argum;
 cout<<"PROCESS "<<arg1->name1<<" HAS ENTERED THE TIMER"<<endl; //this output arg1->name1 as 1.4013e-45
 cout<<"Time remaining for process is "<<arg1->time1<<endl; //this output arg1->time1 as -1218381144
 cout<<"quantum is "<<arg1->quantum1<<endl; //this output arg1->quantum1 as 5
 }
```

Can anybody tell me why this happened?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Guessing `arg1` is destroyed at some point after the `pthread_create()` call. Can you complete the scope around the `pthread_create()` call? Does `arg1` go out of scope after the call to `pthread_create()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not pass the address of a local object (i.e. created on stack) out of the function. You should allocate it using `malloc`/`new`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you allocated `arg1` on the stack, and that memory got out of scope and reused before the thread started executing. Allocate the arg object on the heap using `malloc` or `new`, and don't forget to de-allocate it after you're done, usually from within the thread you created.